# Chef 'custom' logging level

Tags: windows, logging, chef-infra

Is there any way to easily change standard output of Chef run script?
I mean Chef is writing many useless info for normal user, like:

```
[2015-08-06T12:09:30+02:00] INFO: Storing updated cookbooks/windows/resources/auto_run.rb in the cache.
[2015-08-06T12:09:30+02:00] INFO: Storing updated cookbooks/windows/resources/batch.rb in the cache.
[2015-08-06T12:09:30+02:00] INFO: Storing updated cookbooks/windows/resources/feature.rb in the cache.
[2015-08-06T12:09:30+02:00] INFO: Storing updated cookbooks/windows/resources/certificate_binding.rb in the cache.
[2015-08-06T12:09:30+02:00] INFO: Storing updated cookbooks/windows/resources/certificate.rb in the cache.
[2015-08-06T12:09:30+02:00] INFO: Storing updated cookbooks/windows/resources/font.rb in the cache.
```

etc. For me it should be more like debug infos...

Normal user would like to see app-specific info, like:

```
[2015-08-06T12:09:33+02:00] WARN: You're about to remove these resources from your system:
[2015-08-06T12:09:33+02:00] WARN:           - App a (path_to_a)
[2015-08-06T12:09:33+02:00] WARN:           - App b (path_to_b)
[2015-08-06T12:09:33+02:00] WARN:           - App c (path_to_c)
```

but these informations can't be easily read from log since there are tons of other Chef infos.

As you can see on my example, I've used another way: I've set my logs to `warn` level and set Chef log to show only warns by adding these lines to config.rb:

```
log_level           :warn
log_location        "#{path}/log.txt"
```

This works good, but users are annoyed by `WARN` instead of `INFO` word. And I would like to show warnings somehow different than infos...

So - Is there way to disable standard Chef output? And I'm asking for a way without editing Chef install - only config file or something like this.

---

**Specification:**

1. Chef 12.4.1 (chef-client, local mode)
2. Windows 7

Comment: Do you mean to change a specific log statement from INFO level to another level?  Or you mean.. you don't want any logging statements except those generated by your own code?  No, other than the log level, no way to control that.  Sounds a bit like you need your own custom logging code if you really need this behavior (though it sounds suspect as a good requirement to me).

Comment: I thought there would be any way to disable these infos about copying/storing objects or create custom level (like :info, :warn etc.) - this way there would be only mine infos. I do realize that the second way is almost impossible and didn't find any ways to realize first option... I've found in web that you can create your own logger code, but I didn't find any convenient tutorial for this.